# What takes precedence SBT_OPTS or .sbtopts?

Tags: sbt

I've seen both mentioned in articles, blogs, and SO answers, but unclear which I should use in my projects?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is in the [help command](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-launcher-package/blob/master/src/universal/bin/sbt#L465)

```
  # jvm options and output control
  JAVA_OPTS           environment variable, if unset uses "$default_java_opts"
  .jvmopts            if this file exists in the current directory, its contents
                      are appended to JAVA_OPTS
  SBT_OPTS            environment variable, if unset uses "$default_sbt_opts"
  .sbtopts            if this file exists in the current directory, its contents
                      are prepended to the runner args
  /etc/sbt/sbtopts    if this file exists, it is prepended to the runner args
  -Dkey=val           pass -Dkey=val directly to the java runtime
  -J-X                pass option -X directly to the java runtime
                      (-J is stripped)
  -S-X                add -X to sbt's scalacOptions (-S is stripped)
In the case of duplicated or conflicting options, the order above
shows precedence: JAVA_OPTS lowest, command line options highest.
```

Since option lower on list have higher precedence we can assume that `.sbtopts` have precedence over `SBT_OPTS`. It make sense as you could set up `SBT_OPTS` in your `.bashrc` and there should be a way of automatically overriding it per project that `.sbtopts` provides.